# $Mset_{3}$ generating function

Tags: combinatorics

I have to use the fact that $M(x,y)=\prod_{n} (1-yx^{n})^{-a_{n}} $ to find its genereting function.

With $Pset_{3}(x)$ I did something like this:
As $Pset(x) = \prod_{n}(1+yx^n)^{a_{n}}$ to obtain $y^3$ I can choose three brackets in the same $a_k$, two the same and one different and all different. So I can write something like this:
$$Pset_{3}(x)=\sum_{n} \binom{a_n}{3}x^{3n}+\sum_{k \neq j}\binom{a_k}{2}a_jx^{2k+j}+\sum_{k<j<i}a_ja_ka_ix^{k+j+i} $$ and then I get the answer. 
But how can I do something similiar to get $Mset_{3}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[y^q]$  to denote the coefficient of $y^q$ in a series and obtain similarly as OP did above:

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[y^3]\prod_n}&\color{blue}{\left(1-yx^n\right)^{-a_n}}\\
> &=[y^3]\prod_n\sum_{q=0}^\infty\binom{-a_n}{q}\left(-yx^n\right)^q\tag{1}\\
> &=[y^3]\prod_n\sum_{q=0}^\infty\binom{a_n+q-1}{q}x^{nq}y^q\tag{2}\\
> &=[y^3]\prod_n\sum_{q=0}^\infty\left(1+a_nx^{n}y+\binom{a_n+1}{2}x^{2n}y^2+\binom{a_n+2}{3}x^{3n}y^3\right)\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_n\binom{a_n+2}{3}x^{3n}+\sum_{k \neq j}\binom{a_k+1}{2}a_jx^{2k+j}+\sum_{k<j<i}a_ka_ja_ix^{k+j+i}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1)     we use *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* expansion.
- In (2) we apply the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we skip terms which do not contribute to $[y^3]$.
- In (4) we collect the terms which contribute to $[y^3]$  in the same way as OP did.